# Execute npm install in Jenkins only if the package.json has changes

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am building(mvn) my project using Jenkins. Jenkins configured to run `npm install` and `bower install`. So each and every time when I build my project, the `npm install` will run, so the build time is more every time. So I thought to run `npm install` only if there is any changes, like new package is added, version changes or anything got removed etc., in package.json. 
I googled a lot to find out a way to achieve this, but failed.

Is there any plugins which I can use to achieve this?

Can anyone help me to find out a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my experience with Jenkins, it builds your complete project everytime. Which means it doesn't store whichever dependencies are downloaded during a previous build. I don't think it is possible to store your dependencies during builds, but if anyone finds a method for that I would want to know too.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. But in case, if have many depedencies to be installed, the build will take much time right? Nothing can be done on that?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, that is why I don't build with Jenkins every time I make a change. In an ideal situation you would have enough test coverage so you could just run the tests to see if everything still works. Jenkins builds should be limited to a couple per day max, because they just to take a big amount of time.

Comment: I forgot to point out that, my project is in ember.js, so is there any plugin in ember which will help in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience in Ember.js, looks interesting, but haven't had the time :(

Comment: Thanks for reply. Anyone else can help me in this?

Comment: @VineethKoppai if oNaiPs answer helped you please mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as you and wrote `npm-install-changed`.

Install with `npm install -g npm-install-changed`, and run npm-install-changed instead of the usual `npm install`.
Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/), then you can use a **built-in condition** to execute the **stage** if the build’s SCM `changeset` contains one or more files matching the given string or glob. Example:

```
stage('Install dependencies') {
  when {
    changeset "package.json"
  }
  steps {
      sh 'npm install'
  }
}
```

The `when` directive allows the Pipeline to determine whether the stage should be executed depending on the given condition.

You can also run `npm install` and `npm build` only if the code has changed.

```
stage('Build') {
  when {
    anyOf {
      changeset "src/**/*.ts"
      changeset "package.json"
    }
  }
  steps {
      sh 'npm install'
      sh 'npm build'
  }
}
```

The `anyOf` execute the **stage** when at least one of the nested conditions is true.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Jenkins environment variables if using Git and run a command like this

```
git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT | grep package.json && npm install
```

This will run NPM install only when there is a change in `package.json`